Block Spacing and Alignment Formatting for Beamer Poster
I am creating a poster in LaTeX using beamerposter, but am having an issue with block spacing and alignment.
Spacing issues arise whenever lowercase letters like "p" and "g" are used.
Here is a MWE
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    % Title and author information
    \begin{center}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Title} \\[0.5cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\small Author \\[0.2cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\small Institution
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{1cm} % Adjust the spacing as needed
    
    \begin{columns}

        % First column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
                Your introduction text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
                Your methods text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Second column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
                Your results text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
                Your discussion text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Third column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
                Your conclusion text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
                Your references go here.
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
                Your acknowledgements go here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


As you are anyway wrapping all your block titles into a custom macro instead of setting the corresponding beamer font to bold, you could use your macro to make sure that all the block title will have the same height, irregardless of descenders:
\documentclass[final,portrait]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=custom,width=90,height=120,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}

% Load additional packages as needed
%\usepackage{graphicx} % For including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % For nicer tables
%\usepackage{multicol} % For multi-column layout

% Define the column separation and margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{2cm}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0mm}

% Define colors
\definecolor{blue}{RGB}{0, 0, 255}

% Customize the beamer color theme
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=blue}

% Custom block title formatting
\newcommand{\blocktitle}[1]{\vphantom{A}\smash{#1}}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}

% Document begins
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t]
    % Title and author information
    \begin{center}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in head/foot}\textbf{\Huge Title} \\[0.5cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in head/foot}\small Author \\[0.2cm]
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\small Institution
    \end{center}
    
    \vspace{1cm} % Adjust the spacing as needed
    
    \begin{columns}[t]

        % First column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Introduction}}
                Your introduction text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Methods}}
                Your methods text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Second column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Results}}
                Your results text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Discussion}}
                Your discussion text goes here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

        % Third column
        \begin{column}{0.3\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Conclusion}}
                Your conclusion text goes here.
            \end{block}

            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{References}}
                Your references go here.
            \end{block}
            \begin{block}{\blocktitle{Acknowledgements}}
                Your acknowledgements go here.
            \end{block}
        \end{column}

    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


